# Visual Studio / Docker dev vs latest?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I have a ASP.NET Core solution with a Dockerfile and docker-compose.
If I right-click the Dockerfile and select "Build Docker image", I get a new :latest in my list of images in Docker.

If, however, I run the project, it seems to use a :dev image that is 1 day old.

How do I get it to use the :latest when running docker compose? I assume that I somehow need to get it to update the :dev, since it seems to be an old build (shows as 1 day old, and is considerably smaller, since I have added some stuff to the Dockerfile since then).

EDIT: If i run Release, it does use the :latest image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to your queries lie in fast optimizations that are done by Visual Studio when running in development/debug mode. Please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019

> When building in Debug configuration, there are several optimizations
> that Visual Studio does that help with the performance of the build
> process for containerized projects. The build process for
> containerized apps is not as straightforward as simply following the
> steps outlined in the Dockerfile. Building in a container is much
> slower than building on the local machine. So, when you build in the
> Debug configuration, Visual Studio actually builds your projects on
> the local machine, and then shares the output folder to the container
> using volume mounting. A build with this optimization enabled is
> called a Fast mode build.
>
> In Fast mode, Visual Studio calls docker build with an argument that
> tells Docker to build only the base stage. Visual Studio handles the
> rest of the process without regard to the contents of the Dockerfile.
> So, when you modify your Dockerfile, such as to customize the
> container environment or install additional dependencies, you should
> put your modifications in the first stage. Any custom steps placed in
> the Dockerfile's build, publish, or final stages will not be executed.

If you want to disable the performance optimization and build as the Dockerfile specifies, then set the ContainerDevelopmentMode property to Regular in the project file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <ContainerDevelopmentMode>Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```